# Need Help Adding User's Text To NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am prompting users for text when they click the + for my table.  They are shown a UIAlert with textField prompt and the text is then saved as a string in a dictionary.

I have the following code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSArray *myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"]; 

    if (myData == nil)
    {
      myData = [NSMutableArray array];  
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];

    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
    }
}
```

The NSlog shows the entered text but how do I get it to save in my Array?

Also, should I save the text as a string, a dictionary with a string in it, or an array itself with a string in it?  Because there is going to be a dictionary or array within each of these other dictionaries with objects that the user can choose from (the objects they can choose from are stored in a separate plist).

For example, User types in "Arms Day" for the prompt, then it saves to the array and he can choose from all the exercises for the arm that I have stored in a data.plist

Update with new code:

```
#import "RoutineTableViewController.h"
#import "AlertPrompt.h"

@implementation RoutineTableViewController
@synthesize routineArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    /*
    NSArray *myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"]; 

    if (myData == nil)
    {
      myData = [NSMutableArray array];  
    }
    */

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];

    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
        [self.routineArray addObject:entered];    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // do delete
        // get count of rows in UITableView and hide table if it's empty
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [routineArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Update 3:

```
@implementation RoutineTableViewController
@synthesize myArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    myData = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"] retain]; 

    if (myData == nil)
    {
        myData = [NSMutableArray array];  
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem * addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(showPrompt)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

-(void)showPrompt
{
    AlertPrompt *prompt = [AlertPrompt alloc];
    prompt = [prompt initWithTitle:@"Add Workout Day" message:@"\n \n Please enter title for workout day" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" okButtonTitle:@"Add"];

    [prompt show];
    [prompt release];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
        //if(myData && entered)
        {
            [myArray addObject:entered];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    [tableView reloadData];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // do delete
        // get count of rows in UITableView and hide table if it's empty
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [myArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Faisal: Where is the code for creating "routineArray" ?

Comment: Ahh might of deleted that by mistake. Let me add that back into viewdidload.

Comment: ok so I got NSLog to output the array and it seems correct, but the table is not updating with any data.  This is my cell text code:     `cell.textLabel.text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
`

Comment: So when I check the NSCode of from     NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]); I only get the first thing I inputed into the textfield.  if I enter a second or third thing, the NSlog still only shows the first one.

Comment: @Faisal: When you done with the updation of your myArray, just call the reloadData function on your UITableView instance.  [myTableView reloadData];

Comment: Ive actually tried that already but the table is still not loading the text

Comment: I just updated the original post again with my current up to date code.

Comment: Plz use the below modified functions - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myArray count];
}

Comment: Wow how did I overlook that? Its always the small mistakes that take the most time.  thanks so much!

Comment: Ok sure thanks I just did that.  I'm going to try to make the list editable and moveable and also need to save it to user's directory.  Ill make another separate question for that if you are interested in answering it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you to save the user text in `NSMutableArray`.

**Declare NSMutableArray variable in your .h file,**

```
  NSMutableArray *myData;
```

**In Source file .m:**

```
 myData = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"] retain]; 

    if (myData == nil)
    {
      myData = [NSMutableArray array];  
    }
```

**Add text in Array.**

```
if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", entered]);
        if(myData && entered)
        {
              [myArray addObject:entered];
        }
    }
```

Comment: u have to alloc the nsmutable array before u save any data in myData. and their should be no star in   myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"];

Comment: I tried this but am getting null from myArray when I NSLog it

Comment: @Faisal :where did you put the NSLog ?

Comment: this is my nslog:     NSLog(@"%@",[myArray objectAtIndex:0]).  And i put it in the method for: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the current answers are very helpful, because they haven't looked at your code! Just doing `addObject` won't help you, in fact your code probably won't compile if you add it.

Your array is a local variable, so it's only available inside the `viewDidLoad` method. If you try to add anything to it inside your`willDismissWithButtonIndex` method without changing how you're declaring your array you'll cause a compiler error. The first step is to make your `myData` variable available to all your methods. You can use a property to achieve this - if you're unsure how to declare a property you should think about perhaps stepping back and reading up a bit more on Objective-C before diving in.

So, in your header file you might declare:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;`

And in your implementation file:

```
@synthesize myArray
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"mydata"]; 

....


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        NSString *entered = [(AlertPrompt *)alertView enteredText];
        [self.myArray addObject:entered];
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks lxt, I appreciate your answer.  But I had the if method in the viewDidLoad and want to keep it, that is why I was using the array as a local variable.

Comment: You can still keep the array assignment in `viewDidLoad`. A global variable simply means the array can be accessed by any method throughout your class. If you use a local variable it will only be usable inside `viewDidLoad`, which isn't going to be any good for you.

Comment: i think myData should be allocated otherWise it will not store data.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  One last thing, shouldn't this work to populate my table?

  `cell.textLabel.text = [self.routineArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: Should do - I don't know what routineArray is, but as long as it contains NSStrings that would work.

Comment: routineArray = myData , just changed the name sorry

Comment: [cell.textLabel setText:textTemp]; it should be something like that

Comment: for some reason the text is not populating the array, maybe I have to do a reload or something?  I updated the original post with the code Im using.

Comment: There is no need to use getter in alerrview callback btw.

Answer (score -1):

Make your array as part of your class and use its reference in your method to add it to array.

```
[myArray addObject:entered];
```

Comment: This won't work, praveen hasn't read your code - you need to declare your array as a property or make it a global variable.

Comment: @lxt - When i say make it part of class it implies that you declare it as a class variable with property retain, so that one can access it in the method. Did you read the answer? Clearly the guy has the variable in his didload method and doesnt know how to use it in the alert view callback.