# Need To Make Array Editable, Moveable, and Savable To Disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is my previous thread: [Need Help Adding User's Text To NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402258/need-help-adding-users-text-to-nsarray).

I want to enable the edit, delete, and move buttons for my array in the UIViewTable.

The ViewController has the following methods commented out by default but I'm not sure which ones and how to use them.

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/29/iphone-sdk-tutorial-add-delete-reorder-uitableview-row/

hey look out that link

i think it will help

Comment: ok, thanks.  Im actually a little confused as I already have an edit/done button in the right nav bar and an insert button in the left navbar.  which methods should I uncomment or add to make this work?  The tutorial is kind of confusing because it makes you start from scratch.

Comment: You probably also want a NSMutableArray instead of NSArray as your datasource.

Comment: hey faisal i think u have to get listen some video tutorials from utube. then go ahead .before that u will be get more confusing.got it.